# My Electron App is not connecting to server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, electron, mssql-jdbc

I have my electron.exe file, and it's not being able to connect with my server. I work at a company that has this server, and with my computer, I can connect to it through the SSMS app, but when I try to connect with the Electron App, it says that it cannot connect to it...

I'm using the 'mssql'

I've set it free the port 1433, in the firewall as well.
It's weird because in the SSMS app it connects easily, I use the connection like tcp:SERVER/DB,1433 (which is the port that I've set it free)...

That's my connection configuration

```
var dbConfig = {
            user: 'sa',
            password: '123456',
            server: 'SERVER\DB',
            port: '1433',
            trustServerCertificate: true,
            database: 'APPDATA',
            requestTimeout: 600000,
            options: {
                trustedConnection: true,
                useUTC: true
            },
            pool: {
                idleTimeoutMillis: 600000,
            }
        }
```

And I get the error

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to SERVER\DB in 15000ms

I hope you guys can help me out

Comment: Execute the command:
`telnet your-own-host your-own-port`
If this command return timeout or any connection error, your problem won't at electron error but in your connects. In the general cases the problem is in the connectivity, so try to garantee it first

Comment: There's both an instance name and a port number in the connection configuration. Choose one or the other, don't use both, and if you already know which port number the instance is listening on then just use that.

Comment: There's both a `user`+`password` in the connection configuration (i.e.: SQL Logon details) as well as `options.trustedConnection: true` (telling it to use Windows Authentication). Choose one authentication type or the other, don't use both.

Comment: Aside... do not use `sa` credentials in your applications. `sa` is the System Administration account and has full control of your SQL Server. Any technically curious user scraping your application code and configuration files will discover those credentials and have full control of your SQL Server.

Comment: Ohh thanks I didn't know about the sa credentials neither these other... Thanks, I'm going to take it off, I found out that it was a firewall problem, I just set it disabled and it worked out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a firewall problem, I just had to disable it and it worked perfectly, there was an conflict.